# API JSON Dictionary that have Sub-Strings returns TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I'm pulling json feed from an API with this code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-holders"

querystring = {"symbol":"zwu.to"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "12345",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "67890"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
source = response.json()

print("Source is: ",type(source))

for item in source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]:
    fees = item["annualReportExpenseRatio"]["fmt"]
    print("Items are: ", type(item))
```

But, when I try to get the fees value, I get stuck with:

> ```
> fees = item['feesExpensesInvestment']
> ```
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I tried using **json.dumps** and **json.loads** to convert the sub-strings to dictionary as well with no success...

Here is the types I get when I print them:

> Source is:  <class 'dict'>
> Items are:  <class 'str'>

Here is the structure of the source object:

```
{"defaultKeyStatistics":{"annualHoldingsTurnover":{},"enterpriseToRevenue":{},"beta3Year":{"raw":0.75,"fmt":"0.75"},"profitMargins":{},"enterpriseToEbitda":{},"52WeekChange":{},"morningStarRiskRating":{},"forwardEps":{},"revenueQuarterlyGrowth":{},"fundInceptionDate":{"raw":1319068800,"fmt":"2011-10-20"},"annualReportExpenseRatio":{},"totalAssets":{"raw":965995584,"fmt":"966M","longFmt":"965,995,584"},"bookValue":{},"fundFamily":"BMO Asset Management Inc","lastFiscalYearEnd":{},"netIncomeToCommon":{},"trailingEps":{},"lastDividendValue":{},"SandP52WeekChange":{},"priceToBook":{},"nextFiscalYearEnd":{},"yield":{"raw":0.0794,"fmt":"7.94%"},"mostRecentQuarter":{},"enterpriseValue":{},"priceHint":{"raw":2,"fmt":"2","longFmt":"2"},"threeYearAverageReturn":{"raw":0.0477,"fmt":"4.77%"},"lastSplitDate":{},"lastSplitFactor":null,"legalType":"Exchange Traded Fund","lastDividendDate":{},"morningStarOverallRating":{},"earningsQuarterlyGrowth":{},"priceToSalesTrailing12Months":{},"pegRatio":{},"ytdReturn":{"raw":0.0357,"fmt":"3.57%"},"forwardPE":{},"maxAge":1,"lastCapGain":{},"category":null,"fiveYearAverageReturn":{"raw":0.080699995,"fmt":"8.07%"}},"fundProfile":{"initInvestment":{},"family":"BMO Asset Management Inc","categoryName":null,"initAipInvestment":{},"subseqIraInvestment":{},"brokerages":[],"managementInfo":{"managerName":null,"managerBio":null,"startdate":{}},"subseqInvestment":{},"legalType":"Exchange Traded Fund","styleBoxUrl":"http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/fi/3_0stylelargeeq1.gif","feesExpensesInvestment":{"annualHoldingsTurnover":{"raw":0.3132,"fmt":"31.32%"},"frontEndSalesLoad":{},"annualReportExpenseRatio":{"raw":0.0064999997,"fmt":"0.65%"},"netExpRatio":{},"projectionValues":{},"grossExpRatio":{},"deferredSalesLoad":{},"totalNetAssets":{"raw":29117.04,"fmt":"29,117.04"},"twelveBOne":{}},"maxAge":1,"feesExpensesInvestmentCat":{"annualReportExpenseRatio":{},"frontEndSalesLoad":{},"deferredSalesLoad":{},"twelveBOne":{},"annualHoldingsTurnover":{},"totalNetAssets":{"raw":29117.04,"fmt":"29,117.04"},"projectionValuesCat":{}},"initIraInvestment":{},"subseqAipInvestment":{}},"financialsTemplate":{},"topHoldings":{"preferredPosition":{},"bondPosition":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"convertiblePosition":{},"sectorWeightings":[{"realestate":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"consumer_cyclical":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"basic_materials":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"consumer_defensive":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"technology":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"communication_services":{"raw":0.2491,"fmt":"24.91%"}},{"financial_services":{"raw":0.0021,"fmt":"0.21%"}},{"utilities":{"raw":0.5384,"fmt":"53.84%"}},{"industrials":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"energy":{"raw":0.21040002,"fmt":"21.04%"}},{"healthcare":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}}],"holdings":[{"symbol":"PPL.TO","holdingName":"Pembina Pipeline Corp","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.0588,"fmt":"5.88%"}},{"symbol":"ZUT.TO","holdingName":"BMO Equal Weight Utilities ETF","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.0574,"fmt":"5.74%"}},{"symbol":"T.TO","holdingName":"TELUS Corp","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.053600002,"fmt":"5.36%"}},{"symbol":"ENB.TO","holdingName":"Enbridge Inc","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.052199997,"fmt":"5.22%"}},{"symbol":"FTS.TO","holdingName":"Fortis Inc","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.0519,"fmt":"5.19%"}},{"symbol":"EMA.TO","holdingName":"Emera Inc","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.051,"fmt":"5.10%"}},{"symbol":"TRP.TO","holdingName":"TC Energy Corp","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.0509,"fmt":"5.09%"}},{"symbol":"BCE.TO","holdingName":"BCE Inc","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.0502,"fmt":"5.02%"}},{"symbol":"EXC","holdingName":"Exelon Corp","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.049099997,"fmt":"4.91%"}},{"symbol":"VZ","holdingName":"Verizon Communications Inc","holdingPercent":{"raw":0.049000002,"fmt":"4.90%"}}],"bondHoldings":{"maturity":{},"duration":{},"creditQuality":{},"maturityCat":{},"durationCat":{},"creditQualityCat":{}},"bondRatings":[{"bb":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"aa":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"aaa":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"a":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"other":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"b":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"bbb":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"below_b":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},{"us_government":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}}],"equityHoldings":{"priceToCashflow":{"raw":6.6,"fmt":"6.6"},"priceToSales":{"raw":1.76,"fmt":"1.76"},"priceToBookCat":{},"priceToEarningsCat":{},"medianMarketCapCat":{},"threeYearEarningsGrowthCat":{},"threeYearEarningsGrowth":{},"medianMarketCap":{},"priceToEarnings":{"raw":16.15,"fmt":"16.15"},"priceToBook":{"raw":1.66,"fmt":"1.66"},"priceToSalesCat":{},"priceToCashflowCat":{}},"otherPosition":{},"maxAge":1,"cashPosition":{},"stockPosition":{"raw":0.984,"fmt":"98.40%"}},"price":{"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":12.2,"fmt":"12.20"},"averageDailyVolume3Month":{"raw":157771,"fmt":"157.77k","longFmt":"157,771"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":1611953982,"volume24Hr":{},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"shortName":"BMO COVERED CALL UTILITIES ETF","averageDailyVolume10Day":{"raw":179837,"fmt":"179.84k","longFmt":"179,837"},"longName":"BMO Covered Call Utilities ETF","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.05000019,"fmt":"-0.05"},"currencySymbol":"$","regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"preMarketPrice":{},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"toCurrency":null,"postMarketChange":{},"postMarketPrice":{},"exchangeName":"Toronto","preMarketChange":{},"circulatingSupply":{},"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":12.09,"fmt":"12.09"},"priceHint":{"raw":2,"fmt":"2","longFmt":"2"},"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":12.17,"fmt":"12.17"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":268730,"fmt":"268.73k","longFmt":"268,730.00"},"lastMarket":null,"regularMarketSource":"FREE_REALTIME","openInterest":{},"marketState":"POSTPOST","underlyingSymbol":null,"marketCap":{},"quoteType":"ETF","volumeAllCurrencies":{},"strikePrice":{},"symbol":"ZWU.TO","maxAge":1,"fromCurrency":null,"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-0.0040916684,"fmt":"-0.41%"}},"fundPerformance":{"trailingReturns":{"threeMonth":{"raw":0.045300003,"fmt":"4.53%"},"oneYear":{"raw":-0.0705,"fmt":"-7.05%"},"ytd":{"raw":-0.0705,"fmt":"-7.05%"},"lastBearMkt":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"lastBullMkt":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"fiveYear":{"raw":0.0651,"fmt":"6.51%"},"asOfDate":{"raw":1609372800,"fmt":"2020-12-31"},"tenYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"oneMonth":{"raw":-0.0082,"fmt":"-0.82%"},"threeYear":{"raw":0.026600001,"fmt":"2.66%"}},"performanceOverview":{"bestThreeYrTotalReturn":{},"morningStarReturnRating":{},"ytdReturnPct":{"raw":0.0357,"fmt":"3.57%"},"fiveYrAvgReturnPct":{},"numYearsUp":{},"worstOneYrTotalReturn":{},"oneYearTotalReturn":{"raw":-0.0591,"fmt":"-5.91%"},"numYearsDown":{},"asOfDate":{"raw":1610668800,"fmt":"2021-01-15"},"worstThreeYrTotalReturn":{},"bestOneYrTotalReturn":{},"threeYearTotalReturn":{"raw":0.0477,"fmt":"4.77%"}},"riskOverviewStatistics":{"riskRating":{},"riskStatistics":[{"year":"5y","alpha":{"raw":0.28,"fmt":"0.28"},"beta":{"raw":0.57,"fmt":"0.57"},"meanAnnualReturn":{"raw":0.58,"fmt":"0.58"},"rSquared":{"raw":34.7,"fmt":"34.7"},"stdDev":{"raw":11.43,"fmt":"11.43"},"sharpeRatio":{"raw":0.52,"fmt":"0.52"},"treynorRatio":{"raw":9.65,"fmt":"9.65"}},{"year":"3y","alpha":{"raw":-5.12,"fmt":"-5.12"},"beta":{"raw":0.75,"fmt":"0.75"},"meanAnnualReturn":{"raw":0.3,"fmt":"0.3"},"rSquared":{"raw":51.44,"fmt":"51.44"},"stdDev":{"raw":13.77,"fmt":"13.77"},"sharpeRatio":{"raw":0.17,"fmt":"0.17"},"treynorRatio":{"raw":1.93,"fmt":"1.93"}}]},"riskOverviewStatisticsCat":{"riskStatisticsCat":[]},"performanceOverviewCat":{"bestThreeYrTotalReturn":{},"morningStarReturnRating":{},"ytdReturnPct":{},"fiveYrAvgReturnPct":{},"numYearsUp":{},"worstOneYrTotalReturn":{},"numYearsDown":{},"asOfDate":{},"worstThreeYrTotalReturn":{},"bestOneYrTotalReturn":{}},"trailingReturnsCat":{"threeMonth":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"oneYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"ytd":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"lastBearMkt":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"lastBullMkt":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"fiveYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"tenYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"oneMonth":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"},"threeYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},"maxAge":1,"pastQuarterlyReturns":{"returns":[]},"trailingReturnsNav":{"ytd":{"raw":-0.0713,"fmt":"-7.13%"},"oneMonth":{"raw":-0.0089,"fmt":"-0.89%"},"threeMonth":{"raw":0.0468,"fmt":"4.68%"},"oneYear":{"raw":-0.0713,"fmt":"-7.13%"},"threeYear":{"raw":0.027,"fmt":"2.70%"},"fiveYear":{"raw":0.0647,"fmt":"6.47%"},"tenYear":{"raw":0,"fmt":"0.00%"}},"annualTotalReturns":{"returns":[{"year":"2020","annualValue":{"raw":-0.071293205,"fmt":"-7.13%"}},{"year":"2019","annualValue":{"raw":0.2344374,"fmt":"23.44%"}},{"year":"2018","annualValue":{"raw":-0.0550568,"fmt":"-5.51%"}},{"year":"2017","annualValue":{"raw":0.056948,"fmt":"5.69%"}},{"year":"2016","annualValue":{"raw":0.1951471,"fmt":"19.51%"}},{"year":"2015","annualValue":{"raw":-0.1524073,"fmt":"-15.24%"}},{"year":"2014","annualValue":{"raw":0.1439003,"fmt":"14.39%"}},{"year":"2013","annualValue":{"raw":0.0162982,"fmt":"1.63%"}},{"year":"2012","annualValue":{"raw":0.0387747,"fmt":"3.88%"}}],"returnsCat":[]}},"quoteType":{"exchange":"TOR","shortName":"BMO COVERED CALL UTILITIES ETF","longName":"BMO Covered Call Utilities ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","isEsgPopulated":false,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":"-18000000","quoteType":"ETF","symbol":"ZWU.TO","messageBoardId":"finmb_139615776","market":"ca_market"},"summaryDetail":{"previousClose":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"regularMarketOpen":{"raw":12.2,"fmt":"12.20"},"twoHundredDayAverage":{"raw":12.09087,"fmt":"12.09"},"trailingAnnualDividendYield":{},"payoutRatio":{},"volume24Hr":{},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"navPrice":{"raw":12.48,"fmt":"12.48"},"averageDailyVolume10Day":{"raw":179837,"fmt":"179.84k","longFmt":"179,837"},"totalAssets":{"raw":965995584,"fmt":"966M","longFmt":"965,995,584"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"fiftyDayAverage":{"raw":12.27697,"fmt":"12.28"},"trailingAnnualDividendRate":{},"open":{"raw":12.2,"fmt":"12.20"},"toCurrency":null,"averageVolume10days":{"raw":179837,"fmt":"179.84k","longFmt":"179,837"},"expireDate":{},"yield":{"raw":0.0794,"fmt":"7.94%"},"algorithm":null,"dividendRate":{},"exDividendDate":{},"beta":{},"circulatingSupply":{},"startDate":{},"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":12.09,"fmt":"12.09"},"priceHint":{"raw":2,"fmt":"2","longFmt":"2"},"currency":"CAD","regularMarketVolume":{"raw":268730,"fmt":"268.73k","longFmt":"268,730"},"lastMarket":null,"maxSupply":{},"openInterest":{},"marketCap":{},"volumeAllCurrencies":{},"strikePrice":{},"averageVolume":{"raw":157771,"fmt":"157.77k","longFmt":"157,771"},"priceToSalesTrailing12Months":{},"dayLow":{"raw":12.09,"fmt":"12.09"},"ask":{"raw":12.17,"fmt":"12.17"},"ytdReturn":{},"askSize":{"raw":0,"fmt":null,"longFmt":"0"},"volume":{"raw":268730,"fmt":"268.73k","longFmt":"268,730"},"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":14.78,"fmt":"14.78"},"forwardPE":{},"maxAge":1,"fromCurrency":null,"fiveYearAvgDividendYield":{},"fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":9.11,"fmt":"9.11"},"bid":{"raw":12.15,"fmt":"12.15"},"tradeable":false,"dividendYield":{},"bidSize":{"raw":0,"fmt":null,"longFmt":"0"},"dayHigh":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"}},"symbol":"ZWU.TO","assetProfile":{"phone":"800-668-7327","longBusinessSummary":"BMO Covered Call Utilities ETF seeks to provide exposure to the performance of a portfolio of utilities companies to generate income and to provide long-term capital appreciation while mitigating downside risk through the use of covered call options.","companyOfficers":[],"maxAge":86400},"esgScores":{},"pageViews":{},"quoteData":{"ZWU.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":12.2,"fmt":"12.20"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953982,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"9.11 - 14.78","fmt":"9.11 - 14.78"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"shortName":"BMO COVERED CALL UTILITIES ETF","longName":"BMO Covered Call Utilities ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.05000019,"fmt":"-0.05"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":12.22,"fmt":"12.22"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-2.6099997,"fmt":"-2.61"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":3.0600004,"fmt":"3.06"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":12.09,"fmt":"12.09"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":12.17,"fmt":"12.17"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":268730,"fmt":"268,730","longFmt":"268,730"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1327415400000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZWU.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.33589467,"fmt":"33.59%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"12.09 - 12.22","fmt":"12.09 - 12.22"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_139615776","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":14.78,"fmt":"14.78"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.17658997,"fmt":"-17.66%"},"uuid":"f3277957-ea5b-3bb8-9d3a-f118e537a648","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":9.11,"fmt":"9.11"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-0.40916684,"fmt":"-0.41%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false},"ZWB.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":17.8,"fmt":"17.80"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953972,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"11.44 - 18.97","fmt":"11.44 - 18.97"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":17.8,"fmt":"17.80"},"shortName":"BMO COVERED CALL CANADIAN BANKS","longName":"BMO Covered Call Canadian Banks ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.3199997,"fmt":"-0.32"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":17.86,"fmt":"17.86"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-1.4299984,"fmt":"-1.43"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":6.1000013,"fmt":"6.10"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":17.5,"fmt":"17.50"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":17.54,"fmt":"17.54"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":156079,"fmt":"156,079","longFmt":"156,079"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1296743400000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZWB.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.5332169,"fmt":"53.32%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"17.5 - 17.8","fmt":"17.50 - 17.80"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_116776236","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":18.97,"fmt":"18.97"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.0753821,"fmt":"-7.54%"},"uuid":"b5f79cee-b01e-3b5b-8855-cc1b4df00852","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":11.44,"fmt":"11.44"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-1.7917116,"fmt":"-1.79%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false},"ZWE.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":17.78,"fmt":"17.78"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953970,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"13.37 - 21.25","fmt":"13.37 - 21.25"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":17.8,"fmt":"17.80"},"shortName":"BMO EUROPE HIGH DIV CC CAD HEDG","longName":"BMO Europe High Dividend Covered Call Hedged to CAD ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.29999924,"fmt":"-0.30"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":17.92,"fmt":"17.92"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-3.6299992,"fmt":"-3.63"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":4.250001,"fmt":"4.25"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":17.5,"fmt":"17.50"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":17.62,"fmt":"17.62"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":109589,"fmt":"109,589","longFmt":"109,589"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1441978200000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZWE.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.31787592,"fmt":"31.79%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"17.5 - 17.8","fmt":"17.50 - 17.80"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_306614108","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":21.25,"fmt":"21.25"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.17082348,"fmt":"-17.08%"},"uuid":"f6bcc1ef-949a-3256-872d-9865d20fdac7","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":13.37,"fmt":"13.37"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-1.6741028,"fmt":"-1.67%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false},"ZWH.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":19.95,"fmt":"19.95"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953942,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"14.36 - 22.01","fmt":"14.36 - 22.01"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":19.95,"fmt":"19.95"},"shortName":"BMO US HIGH DIVIDEND COVERED CA","longName":"BMO US High Dividend Covered Call ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.3199997,"fmt":"-0.32"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":20.02,"fmt":"20.02"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-2.3099995,"fmt":"-2.31"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":5.340001,"fmt":"5.34"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":19.65,"fmt":"19.65"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":19.7,"fmt":"19.70"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":58550,"fmt":"58,550","longFmt":"58,550"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1392388200000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZWH.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.37186638,"fmt":"37.19%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"19.65 - 19.95","fmt":"19.65 - 19.95"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_253436770","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":22.01,"fmt":"22.01"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.10495227,"fmt":"-10.50%"},"uuid":"a8bcb3d3-2a14-3815-9d69-4f6f49aa1c29","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":14.36,"fmt":"14.36"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-1.5984001,"fmt":"-1.60%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false},"ZWC.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":16.3,"fmt":"16.30"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953970,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"11.48 - 19.43","fmt":"11.48 - 19.43"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":16.33,"fmt":"16.33"},"shortName":"BMO CDN HIGH DIV COVERED CALL E","longName":"BMO CA High Dividend Covered Call ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.23999977,"fmt":"-0.24"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":16.39,"fmt":"16.39"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-3.2800007,"fmt":"-3.28"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":4.67,"fmt":"4.67"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":16.06,"fmt":"16.06"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":16.15,"fmt":"16.15"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":377094,"fmt":"377,094","longFmt":"377,094"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1487082600000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZWC.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.40679446,"fmt":"40.68%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"16.06 - 16.33","fmt":"16.06 - 16.33"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_414472744","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":19.43,"fmt":"19.43"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.16881114,"fmt":"-16.88%"},"uuid":"9af002d6-34e0-3f56-b496-eb432a8bc694","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":11.48,"fmt":"11.48"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-1.4643062,"fmt":"-1.46%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false},"ZUT.TO":{"sourceInterval":15,"quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote","regularMarketOpen":{"raw":25.9,"fmt":"25.90"},"exchange":"TOR","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1611953997,"fmt":"3:59PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"14.53 - 27.14","fmt":"14.53 - 27.14"},"regularMarketDayHigh":{"raw":25.94,"fmt":"25.94"},"shortName":"BMO EQUAL WEIGHT UTILITIES INDE","longName":"BMO Equal Weight Utilities Index ETF","exchangeTimezoneName":"America/Toronto","regularMarketChange":{"raw":-0.19000053,"fmt":"-0.19"},"regularMarketPreviousClose":{"raw":25.95,"fmt":"25.95"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":{"raw":-1.3799992,"fmt":"-1.38"},"exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EST","fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":{"raw":11.2300005,"fmt":"11.23"},"exchangeDataDelayedBy":15,"regularMarketDayLow":{"raw":25.43,"fmt":"25.43"},"priceHint":2,"currency":"CAD","regularMarketPrice":{"raw":25.76,"fmt":"25.76"},"regularMarketVolume":{"raw":142395,"fmt":"142,395","longFmt":"142,395"},"isLoading":false,"triggerable":true,"gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-18000000,"firstTradeDateMilliseconds":1264429800000,"region":"US","marketState":"POSTPOST","quoteType":"ETF","invalid":false,"symbol":"ZUT.TO","language":"en-US","fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":{"raw":0.7728837,"fmt":"77.29%"},"regularMarketDayRange":{"raw":"25.43 - 25.94","fmt":"25.43 - 25.94"},"messageBoardId":"finmb_83524588","fiftyTwoWeekHigh":{"raw":27.14,"fmt":"27.14"},"fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":{"raw":-0.050847426,"fmt":"-5.08%"},"uuid":"674b2651-4b39-3f74-8dcd-9f99c0b425fd","market":"ca_market","fiftyTwoWeekLow":{"raw":14.53,"fmt":"14.53"},"regularMarketChangePercent":{"raw":-0.7321793,"fmt":"-0.73%"},"fullExchangeName":"Toronto","tradeable":false}},"mktmData":{}}
```

How can I fix this, please?

Comment: if the `item` is of type `str` as you pointed, you can't use `item["annualReportExpenseRatio"]["fmt"]`. please provide the structure of the `source` object so that we can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided structure this is all you need:

```
print(source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]["annualReportExpenseRatio"])
```

Output:

```
 {'raw': 0.0064999997, 'fmt': '0.65%'}
```

To just get the `fmt` value, use the following:

```
print(source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]["annualReportExpenseRatio"]["fmt"])
```

Output: `0.65%`

If there are multiple key-value pairs for the result, you can iterate over them using a loop and get all the values.

Comment: this works now:  print(source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]["annualReportExpenseRatio"]['fmt']) but I get 0.65% 9 times, how can I get it just once?
(Back to the original issue, if I use **for** loop it will return the **str KeyErro**

Comment: without knowing the full input, I am not sure there is much help I can do. May be just add the elements to the list and use only the first element if you don't want them all.

Comment: I added the full json sent from the API

Comment: I don't understand why you need the loop. I get the desired output with just `print(source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]["annualReportExpenseRatio"])`

Comment: I love you man!!! It works now!!! Got stuck in it for a full day...
It was looping because I un-purposely indented your code...

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided the JSON that you are getting back from the API so we can look at its structure and give a better answer.

Are you sure the sub-strings that you are getting are in a valid JSON format? If not, you won't be able to do `json.loads()` on them.

If they are not in JSON format or any other well-known structured format, you may have to rely on parsing the string with custom code.

Answer (score 0):

while I tried running the code on my local machine, I got this response:

```
{'message': "API doesn't exists"}
```

But I think the problem here is that your response is formatted in an array of responses. So, you will have to access them through a `for` loop.

If this doesn't solve your issue, please share a sample output of the JSON response you are getting so that it's easier to debug the issue.

Comment: I just added the source structure as requested, API will ask for my account credentials to work.

Comment: Hi, I don't see any reason why this won't work. What I'd recommend you to do is, since the JSON you are getting is not an array, avoid using the for loop. Simply access your required amount with `source["fundProfile"]["feesExpensesInvestment"]["annualReportExpenseRatio"]["fmt"]` I don't think you'd need a for loop unless the required records are in an array of JSON objects.

Comment: if I don't use the **for** loop, I'll get the value 9 times, is there a way to limit it to just one then?

Comment: No, that's what I said, if the response is an array, you have to use for loop. The sample you shared doesn't show it as an array, which is why I suggested not to go for a for loop